# Can't store 32-bit float in 64-bit long

Tags: assembly, clang, 64-bit, x86-64, inline-assembly

Clang can't compile the following code:

```c
long Result = 0;
__asm {
    ; call 32-bit float-returning function, then
    MOVSS Result, xmm0
};
```

I'm getting "error : invalid operand for instruction", pointing to `MOVSS qword ptr Result, xmm0`.

I'm using clang++ 5.0.300080, targeting x86_64 for Android, and passing `-fasm-blocks`.

I've checked on Godbolt/Compiler Explorer, but it has no problem producing the code with Clang 5.0.1.

Any fixes or workarounds besides making Result a 32-bit variable?

Cheers

Comment: If you want to store to the low 32 bits of a 64-bit `long` (and leave the upper 32 bits unmodified), write `movss dword ptr [Result], xmm0`.  A 64-bit reload will cause a store-forwarding stall.  But really you should just use `uint32_t Result`; the compiler/assembler is doing its job here and saving you from yourself with an operand-size mismatch.  It even showed you `qword ptr`.  IDK why you want to store to memory at all with inline asm, instead of just type-punning in pure C (after using GNU C inline asm syntax to produce a `float` output if you really want to use asm)

Comment: Is long 32 or 64 bit on Android?

Comment: @Sebastian it's 64-bit, in the x86_64 build I'm doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not familiar with assembly, I got it from another coder - a few hundred lines that worked fine in Apple Clang, but this line was the one that choked when building for Android. Feel free to spin it into an answer and I'll mark it as answered!

Comment: The long is used to either store a pointer, an 32-bit int, or a 32-bit float, hence the confusion of sizes. It's part of a necessary evil wrapper between two systems.

Comment: The code might have been written for a system with 32-bit pointers and 32-bit `long`, so I wouldn't assume everything is going to work with just this change.  If you don't know asm, you're not going to be able to check what it's loading from and storing to, if it's structs that include `long` or something.

Comment: It's specifically x64, there's 4 CPU types at work, all separated by preprocessor and with their own ASMs. So I'm confident the long size won't be 32-bit. The coder made it according to the spec I gave, and there was a non-assembly solution, albeit generated by a tool at compile time and very verbose with a lot of casting.

Comment: Did Peter's first comment work? (`dword ptr [result]`) If not, does changing long to int make a difference? In that case a union between long and void* and int could make sense?

Comment: @Phi: I know you're compiling for x86-64.  But since it *doesn't* compile out of the box for that target, I'm wondering if just fixing things like this would make it actually work.  If the code was written assuming 32-bit x86, and/or the Windows x64 ABI (where `long` is a 32-bit type), you may run into other problems.  Windows is maybe relevant because the most common use for `asm {}` code blocks is MSVC's inline asm syntax, which it supports only on 32-bit x86.  (Where `int` and pointers are also 32-bit).

Comment: If the code does any bit-shifts on an FP bit-pattern, it may be expecting that left shifts are shifting bits out the top, so a right shift will shift in zeros, not whatever some earlier left-shift shifted out.

Comment: @Sebastian it does compile, yeah, I would assume it works, but I'll be testing the ASM later. A union was extra fluff I would prefer to avoid, since I'd be returning a long directly as per part of the API the code goes between.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's targeting only 32-bit Windows, thankfully - I did leave notes that the assembly wouldn't run under 64-bit, but since the Windows port is compiled in MSVC, it won't support inline 64-bit anyway. The other targets are all CPUs for iOS and Android - so x64, x86, ARMv7, ARM64. The floats are not manipulated like integers, just straight copied into the long then cast-reinterpreted by the C++ API on the other end (which I can't modify).

Comment: Ok, well beware that clang `-fasm-blocks` doesn't support leaving a value in EAX and falling off the end of a non-`void` function the way MSVC does when inlining the function.  Other than that, yeah if you've checked it over and found everything else is infe, then you might get away with taking inline asm written for x86 MSVC and compiling it for x86-64 Android if it doesn't use any `[eax]` or other 32-bit addressing modes.

Comment: But for cases where a `long` is the target operand, it would make sense to change it to a 32-bit integer type (or just `float`) when being used for a float instead of a pointer.  Having compiler-generated code do 64-bit load/store is going to hurt performance some (store forwarding stall).